# jquery internationalization / globalization

Tags: jquery, localization, internationalization

I am looking at using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/ to provide localization features to terms in my javascript code.  I can't make much sense of the documentation provided.  If I have english terms "open" and "close" and want to also use french "ouvrir" and "fermer" - is there a good example anywhere on how I would use this plugin?  I'm not having any luck finding anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always [contact the developer](http://codingwithcoffee.com/) or view the [demo page](http://codingwithcoffee.com/files/trunk/index.html).

It appears you [build a map](http://codingwithcoffee.com/files/trunk/bundle/Messages.properties) for each language ([pt](http://codingwithcoffee.com/files/trunk/bundle/Messages_pt.properties), [pt_PT](http://codingwithcoffee.com/files/trunk/bundle/Messages_pt_PT.properties)) you wish to support. Calling `loadBundles('pt_PT');` triggers that bundle to be loaded (*or using the browsers language (`jQuery.i18n.browserLang()`*).

You just need to view the source of the demo page for more details.

Comment: Made my way through the source and saw my issue.